# how to disable sorting data in x axis in d3 line chart?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, d3.js

I want show line graph like this example [link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) .my data json is like this.

```
[
    {
       "timeStamp": "23:33:58",
        "usage": 90
    },
    {
        "timeStamp": "00:04:03",
        "usage": 94
    },
    {
        "timeStamp": "00:54:04",
        "usage": 82
    },
    {
        "timeStamp": "01:04:00",
        "usage": 100
    },
    {
        "timeStamp": "01:34:02",
        "usage": 97
    }
]
```

but x axis didn't start with 23:33:58.it start with 00:00:00 mean 12.00 AM and draw it in to 23:59:00.so it is not my requirement .i want solve this problem please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass `timestamp` with date you can solve this problem.then identify about the date and time.so can solve it like this.in example parse timestamp like this.

`var parsetime = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;`

then your json format timestamp change like this

`"timeStamp": "2011-01-01 23:33:58"`

then i think you can solve it.